# jQuery Ajax Success nor Fail methods hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've got the following code below which is supposed to make a call to the controller when a link is clicked. The controller is getting called successfully, but the only method on the javascript side that is hit is `always` which displays a pop up stating "undefined".

### Adding Method to Link

```
$('.retrieveTeam').click(function () {
        _getData($(this).data("teamkey"));
    });
```

### jQuery AJAX Call

```
function _getData(postdata) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: 'RetrieveTeam',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ TeamKey: "331.l.542488.t.1" }),
        datatype: JSON,
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
    request.success = function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
    request.error = function (result, xh) {
        alert("error");
    }
    request.fail = function () {
        alert("failure");
    }
    request.always = function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult RetrieveTeam(string TeamKey)
    {
        List<Team> objTeams = (List<Team>)Session["Teams"];

        Team objTeam = objTeams.Where(x => x.TeamKey == TeamKey).FirstOrDefault();

        objTeam.AddPlayer(new FootballPlayer(new Position("QB", "QB", "QB"), "Brett Favre", "QB"));

        return Json(objTeam);
    }
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery 2.1.1 I've tried both JSON and "json" to the safe effect

Comment: Change `data: JSON.stringify({ TeamKey: "331.l.542488.t.1" }),` to `data: { TeamKey: "331.l.542488.t.1" }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using jQuery 2.1.1. Reading [the manual page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for `$.ajax` we can see that:

> The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are
>   deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual
>   removal, use `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

In your code,

```
request.success = ...
```

should be replaced with

```
request.done(...)
```

and `.fail =` with `.error()` as well. Also, fix your dataType.
All together this brings us to:

```
function _getData(postdata) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'RetrieveTeam',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ TeamKey: "331.l.542488.t.1" }),
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    }).done(function (foo) {

    }).fail(function (foo) {

    }).always(function (foo) {

    });
}
```